# HAProxy: How to retain the url path in the backend local ip?

Tags: domain, path

Aim:

```
url: trigger.mydomain.com ---> backend: 192.168.2.22:8080
url: trigger.mydomain.com/web ---> backend: 192.168.2.22:9999/web
```

I know how to do the first url, but not the second url.
How to specify both the frontend and backend to accomplish this?